# Why do all-pair shortest path algorithms work with negative weights?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I've been studying all-pair shortest path algorithms recently such as Floyd-Warshall and Johnson's algorithm, and I've noticed that these algorithms produce correct solutions even when a graph contains negative weight edges (but not negative weight cycles). For comparison, Dijkstra's algorithm (which is single-source shortest path) does not work for negative weight edges. What makes the all-pair shortest path algorithms work with negative weights?

Comment: It might be instructive to learn why Dijkstra's algorithm _doesn't_ work with negative weights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159337/why-dijkstras-algo-not-work-for-negative-weight-edges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floyd Warshall's all pairs shortest paths algorithm works for graphs with negative edge weights because the correctness of the algorithm does not depend on edge's weight being non-negative, while the correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm is based on this fact.

**Correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm:**

We have 2 sets of vertices at any step of the algorithm. Set A consists of the vertices to which we have computed the shortest paths. Set B consists of the remaining vertices.

**Inductive Hypothesis**: At each step we will assume that all previous iterations are correct.

**Inductive Step**: When we add a vertex V to the set A and set the distance to be dist[V], we must prove that this distance is optimal. If this is not optimal then there must be some other path to the vertex V that is of shorter length.

Suppose this some other path goes through some vertex X in the set B.

Now, since `dist[V] <= dist[X]` , therefore any other path to V will be atleast dist[V] length, unless the graph has negative edge lengths.

**Correctness of Floyd Warshall's algorithm:**
Any path from vertex S to vertex T, will go through any other vertex U of the graph. Thus the shortest path from S to T can be computed as the

> min( shortest_path(S to U) + shortest_path(U to T)) for all vertices U in the graph.

As you can see there is no dependence on the graph's edges to be non-negative as long as the sub calls compute the paths correctly. And the sub calls compute the paths correctly as long as the base cases have been properly initialized.

Comment: You can't just say "Now, since dist[V] <= dist[X]", at least not without qualifying X a bit more.  I think what you need here is to say "Suppose this some other path goes through some vertex X *in B.*" in the previous sentence, and explain why it's not necessary to consider the case where X is in A.

Comment: If the path has to go through some vertex of set A then it will directly start from that vertex. I thought this too basic not to add. However I have added that "X is in set B". Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's Algorithm doesn't work for negative weight edge because it is based on the greedy strategy(an assumption) that once a vertex v was added to the set S, d[v] contains the minimum distance possible.

But if the last vertex in Q was added to S and it has some outgoing negative weight edges. The effects on the distance that caused by negative edges won't count.

However, all pairs shortest paths algorithm will capture those updates.