# Data Structures / undirected graphs and Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I am stuck on a two part practice problem regarding the subjects mentioned in the title.

The first part of the question asks:
By considering the complete graph with n verticies, show that the maximum number of simple paths between two verticies is O((n-1)!).  (I am assuming I am supposed to show this somehow with a formal definition)

The second portion of the questions asks:
Give an example where Dijkstra's algorithm gives the wrong answer in the presence of a negative edge but no negative cost cycles.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are two questions here, and on SO we expect one question per thread. The 2nd question is answered in: [why Dijkstra's algo does not work for negative weight edges](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13159337/572670).

Comment: First question is a simple induction, the second is finding a small example of such a graph (of which, if you can't come up with one yourself, there are numerous to be found online).

Comment: Regarding the first part, there are (n-1)! simple maximal paths (of length `n`), but there are more paths if you consider 1->2->3 as different than 1->2.

Comment: @G.Bach How would I go about proving the induction though?  The only time I have have used induction is when I have two equations set equal to one another.  In this case, we only have one two work with.

Comment: You do induction on the number of vertices of the graph. Start proving it for two vertices, then assume that the bound holds for some n>=2 and prove it for n+1.

Comment: @amit With the addition of "Between two vertices" the upper bound is still correct I believe. The number of simple paths is 1! + 2! + ... + (n-2)! <= (n-2)*(n-2)! <= (n-1)!

Comment: @NiklasB. If you don't restrict yourself to simple paths, then any cycle will give an infinite number of paths, no?

Comment: @G.Bach Of course I meant simple paths. I edited the comment

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses!

Comment: @NiklasB. Well that a subset of all simple paths is smaller than the set of all simple paths is not much additional information.

Comment: @G.Bach  I kind of got stuck here, am I doing this right so far?

O(n-1)!
basis: O(2-1)!=1 This holds true

assume: O(k-1)!
Prove: O((k+1)-1)!
=O(k)!

Comment: @G.Bach There are omega((n-1)!) simple paths in the graph if I'm not mistaken. In fact there should even be omega((n-1)!) simple paths starting at a given vertex, but O((n-1)!) if you fix the end node as well.

Comment: @Nick Yeah that sounds about right; I just realized that maybe a combinatorial proof might be easier.

Comment: @NiklasB: Actually there are exactly (n-1)! simple paths starting at a fixed vertex, and (n-2)! simple paths between two fixed vertices (if we fix which vertex is start and which is target, otherwise there are 2*(n-2)!).

Comment: @G.Bach But that isn't the end of the proof.  Doesn't the induction proof have to prove that it can go back to the original (k-1)! after the induction step?  So from (k)! I need to somehow prove that I can get back to (k-1)!

Comment: @G.Bach That's only the paths of length (n-1). There are many more though

Comment: @NiklasB. You're right, I forgot about those. There may be o((n-1)!) simple paths between two fixed vertices (you could probably use Stirling's approximation for that), but there are definitely Omega((n-1)!) simple paths starting at a given vertex.

Comment: @Nick Maybe induction is not the easiest approach here after all; try thinking about how you can build paths from s to t.

Comment: @G.Bach The only proofs we know so far is induction, and contradiction.  I'm sure I will eventually figure it out.  Thanks for the good start