# As I read Djiktra's algo fails for negative edges but I implemented the same concept and my code is working? Is there some bug?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

The code works for negative edges too and I have used priority queue
please check it and let me know what's wrong with it and why is this working even for negative edges.
Constraint: edges should be less than 10000 length
Am I doing something wrong here?
As I read Djiktra's algo fails for negative edges but I implemented the same concept and my code is working? Is there some bug?

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<queue>
    using namespace std;

    struct reach
    {
        int n;
        int weight;
    };

    struct cmp
    {
        bool operator()(reach a, reach b)
        {
            return a.weight>b.weight;
        }
    };

    class sp
    {
        int *dist;
        int n;
        int **graph;
        int src;
        public:
            sp(int y)
            {
                n=y;
                src=1;
                dist=new int[n+1];
                graph=new int*[n+1];
                for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    graph[i]=new int[n+1];
                }
                for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    dist[i]=10000;
                }
            //  cout<<INT_MAX<<endl;
                dist[src]=0;
                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                    {
                        graph[i][j]=10000;
                    }
                }
                graph[1][1]=0;
            }
            void read()
            {
                int a;
                cout<<"enter number of edges"<<endl;
                cin>>a;
                cout<<"now enter the two vertices which has an edge followed by the weight of the edge"<<endl;
                while(a--)
                    {//cout<<"location: "<<i<<" : "<<j<<endl;
                    int as, ad,val;
                    cin>>as>>ad>>val;


                            graph[as][ad]=val;

                    }

            }
            void finder()
            {cout<<"enetered"<<endl;
                priority_queue<reach, vector<reach>, cmp> q;
                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    if(dist[src]+graph[src][i]<dist[i])
                    {
                        reach temp;
                        temp.n=i;
                        cout<<i<<endl;
                        temp.weight=graph[src][i];
                        q.push(temp);
                        dist[i]=graph[src][i]+dist[src];
                    }
                }
                    while(q.empty()!=1)
                    {
                        reach now =q.top();
                        //cout<<" we have here: "<<now.n<<endl;
                        q.pop();
                        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                        {
                            if((dist[now.n] + graph[now.n][i])<dist[i])
                            {
                                dist[i]=dist[now.n]+graph[now.n][i];
                                cout<<"it is: "<<i<<" : "<<dist[i]<<endl;

                                reach temp;
                                temp.n=i;
                                //cout<<temp.n<<endl;
                                temp.weight=graph[now.n][i];
                                q.push(temp);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

            void print()
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                    cout<<"we have: "<<dist[i]<<" at "<<i;
                    cout<<endl;
                }

                cout<<endl;
            }

        };


        int main()
        {cout<<"enter no. of vertices"<<endl;
            int n;
            cin>>n;
            sp sp(n);
            sp.read();
            sp.finder();
            sp.print();



    }
```

Comment: You may find that it works in some cases, but doesn't work in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799172/negative-weights-using-dijkstras-algorithm

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159337/why-doesnt-dijkstras-algorithm-work-for-negative-weight-edges

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

Undirected Graph(6v,8e)

Edges (v1-v2 (weight)):

- 1-2 (2)
- 2-3 (1)
- 1-3 (-2)
- 1-6 (-2)
- 3-6 (-3)
- 5-6 (1)
- 4-5 (2)
- 2-5 (1)

Now, Let source be `1` and destination be `4`. There is one cycle from source to source (1-3-6-1) which weighs (-7). So, lets list a few paths from source to destination with weights:

- 1-6-5-4 (1)
- 1-3-6-5-4 (-2)
- 1-3-6-1-3-6-5-4 (-9)
- 1-3-6-1-3-6-1-3-6-5-4 (-16)

etc.
So, which path is the shortest? Since it is ambiguous, the algorithm does not work. Now, you can argue that if a node is visited, you will not update it. In this case, you will not get the correct answer. May be there   are some cases where in-spite of having negative edges, algo gives correct results, but this is not how Dijkstra works.

A really simple way to understand Dijkstra is that **it performs BFS on the graph, from source till destination, and in every step it updates the visited nodes.** So, if there is a node `n` which has cost `c` and a few levels deep in bfs, its cost becomes `k (<c)`. Then again you will have to update all the nodes visited from `n` for their shorter paths (because path to `n` is now shorter). Since graph has negative edges, if it has a cycle, `n` will keep updating infinitely and will never end.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest graph for which Dijkstra's algorithm fails with negative weights has adjacency matrix

```
0 1  2
1 0 -3
2 -3 0
```

and looks for a route from vertex `0` to vertex `1`. The first vertex to come off the priority queue is vertex `1` at distance `1`, so that's the route returned. But there was a route of total weight `-1` via a vertex which is still in the priority queue, with weight `2`.