# dijkstra's vs Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, graph-traversal, bellman-ford

my current understanding is that dijkstra's algorithm is more efficient then bellman-ford, only it cannot handle negative edges. However say we have an edge weighted graph where there are negative-weight edges, there are no negative-weight cycles in the graph, can we still use dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159337/why-doesnt-dijkstras-algorithm-work-for-negative-weight-edges) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799172/negative-weights-using-dijkstras-algorithm/6799344#6799344) question.

Comment: This looks like a great question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered well here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13159425/12449779

To summarize, Dijkstra's algorithm in each iteration marks the vertices at **minimum distances** from "marked" vertices. Initially, the source vertex is the only marked vertex with distance 0. Suppose two marked vertices exists A and B who are at a certain finite distance from source and their paths do **not** overlap. Currently, the paths to A and B would be considered as the shortest possible paths from A to B. Since the paths do not overlap, any path from Source to A to B would be of length source to A + length of Path from A to B which is greater than path from source to B as paths from source to A and B do not overlap. But if negative weighted edges are allowed, this does **NOT** hold. As the length of path from A to B may be **negative**. Thus **Dijkstra's Algorithm does not work**. There is no simple way to convert a general graph with negative edges to one with non-negative edges either. Bellman Ford works for any graph which does not contain negative weighted cycles.