# Dijkstra algorithm is not working and gives wrong distances

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I'm implementing Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path between two nodes in a graph, although I see the code is currect it does not work for most of the examples and I don't know why,

my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import math

def Dijkstra(graph, source, goal):
    Distance = {}
    Predecessor = {}
    Q = []
    visited_vertices = set()
    for V in graph.nodes:
        Distance[V] = 0
        Q.append(V)
    Distance[source] = 0
    while Q:
        node_u = find_minimum(Q,Distance)
        Q.remove(node_u)
        visited_vertices.add(node_u)
        for node_v in graph.neighbors(node_u):
            if node_v in visited_vertices:
                continue
            weight_u_v = get_weight(graph, node_u, node_v)
            if Distance[node_u] + weight_u_v < Distance[node_v]:
                Distance[node_v] = Distance[node_u] + weight_u_v
                Predecessor[node_v] = node_u
    return Distance

def find_minimum(Q, Distance):
    minimum = math.inf
    minimum_index = None
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        if Distance[Q[i]] < minimum:
            minimum = Distance[Q[i]]
            minimum_index = i
    return Q[minimum_index]


def get_weight(graph, node_u, node_v):
    return graph.get_edge_data(node_u,node_v)['weight']

def main():
    graph = nx.Graph()
    graph.add_node('V0')
    graph.add_node('V1')
    graph.add_node('V2')
    graph.add_node('V3')
    graph.add_node('V4')
    edges = []
    edges.append(('V0','V1',10))
    edges.append(('V1','V2',5))
    edges.append(('V2','V3',-25))
    edges.append(('V0','V3',3))
    edges.append(('V3','V4',8))
    graph.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)


    d = Dijkstra(graph,'V4','V2')
    print(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

you can copy it and try to run it, for V4 to V2 the output is

```
{'V0': 0, 'V1': 0, 'V2': 0, 'V3': -25, 'V4': -17}
```

where it should be

```
{'V0': -2, 'V1': -12, 'V2': -17, 'V3': 8, 'V4': 0}
```

and I really don't know why this is happening.

Comment: you add nodes to the `visited_vertices` but you never **read** what nodes have been visited  (and treat them as handled).

Comment: Specifying where you think it is in the infinite loop would be helpful.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you! I don't know how that slipped, althought now i'm facing another problem

Comment: Can you provide an expected output?

Comment: You have to initialize distance array for all vertexes except `source` as Infinities, not zeroes. And during the algorithm you will improve distances.

Comment: Dijkstra doesn't work for negative edges..

Comment: I edited @TomMyddeltyn

Comment: sorry can you explain more @IaroslavSviridov

Comment: Here I think this explains it well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159337/why-doesnt-dijkstras-algorithm-work-for-negative-weight-edges

Comment: thank you @TomMyddeltyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithm cannot handle negative weights on edges, you should use [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm to achieve it.

Comment: really? I thought it was the other way around, but I tried previously implementing bellmanford and it has only a way of detecting a negative edge but not give the shortest path in a negative edges graph, do you know which algorithm can give me a the shortest path in a situation like this if one exist? and thanks for helping! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SAAD as I said in answer, you should use Bellman-Ford algorithm, if it doesn't work correctly, it means you made a mistake in its implementation somewhere. Look at the attached wikipedia link for better understanding.