# Modification of Dijkstra's algorithm to make it work with negative weights and its time complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

It is commonly stated (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13159337/5459839)) that Dijkstra's algorithm does not work for graphs with negative weights.

But what if we just modify this algorithm a little bit? Suppose we have a hashmap where the cost of each node is stored, and we also have a hashset where all the processed nodes are contained. If we find a shorter path to an already processed node, then we remove it from the list of processed nodes and add it to the heap again.

In my opinion, the time complexity of such a modified algorithm will differ only by a constant; could you please explain if I am wrong?

If I'm right about the unchanged time complexity, then why is it said that Dijkstra's algorithm is not applicable to graphs with negative weights, if we can use such a modification, and then make it work for negative edges too (assuming no negative cycles)?

Comment: I think this has been nicely answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6799172/1016514

Comment: I answered here yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77985985/5884011

Comment: @Anne, there you assume the weight is stored with the node on the heap, but the asker here has the weights stored in a map, so they are always available.

Comment: @trincot the question is: why Dijkstra's algorithm does not work for graph. My answer was, you modify it, you can, but that's not what the original Dijkstra's algorithm says. It's not I use a heap to implement it, is to represent the ORIGINAL idea, heap is what it needs.

Comment: Yes, that was the question *there*, but here we have a different question, and so your answer *there* doesn't help to answer the question *here*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my opinion, the time complexity of such a modified algorithm will differ only by a constant, please explain if I am wrong

It can differ more than a constant. Here is a category of graphs for which we get a worse time complexity:

[image]

Graphs of this category have 2−1 nodes, numbered from −+1 to −1. The paths from node 0 to node 1 have a decreasing cost as we go "down" first (to nodes -1, -2, -3...) and then back up to node 1.

If we perform Dijkstra's algorithm with source at node 0, the first nodes to expand will be nodes 1 to −1, giving a cost of −1 to reach that rightmost node.

Then node -1 will be expanded, and so the same nodes 1 to −1 will be put on the priority queue again ... giving a reduced cost of −2 to get to that rightmost node.

And so it continues: node -2 will get involved, then node -3, ... until the node at the bottom gets involved. Each time the nodes 1 to −1 would have to be put back on the queue.

So for this subset of graphs (with varying ) the time complexity is O(²) = O(||²), which is worse than what Dijkstra's algorithm ensures for these graphs if they would have the same shape, but no negative weights. Then Dijkstra's algorithm would do the job in O(||log||).

Comment: I would like to ask one more question. The time complexity will actually be ((|V|-m)^2), where m is the number of nodes from 0 to -n+1, but since the constant is discarded, then the complexity (|V|^2) is obtained, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's right! We have 0 to −+1 times that the nodes from 1 to −1 are enqueued, so this represents *(−1) work, which is O(²). And as ||=2−1, this is O([(||+1)/2]²), which is O(||²)

Answer (score 0):

I answered here yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77985985/5884011

Short answer is, you can, but it's not the original Dijkstra's algorithm anymore, it's a variant of it. Remember, the original algorithm is theory based, so it wasn't written like I am going to use a heap/hash do this first then etc. It was written more like the shortest path of any node v is the shortest path to u (the one before it), plus the distance of (u,v) and bunch of proofs why this is correct.

So the hypothesis to start with is anything before v is shortest already. By having a negative edge, you break the assumption that anything before it is the shortest, because from s -> u -> v, even tho u is before v, s -> v is shorter than s -> u.

To Add:

the core problem of negative edge is never about what do I use to keep my stuff, heap, hash, how do I keep it etc. It's the fact you have to run through all edges multiple times. Regardless what you use if you don't do O(V*E) you can't solve it. So it's not a constant factor, and which is why after modifying literally how it works is no longer called the Dijkstra's algorithm, because that's not what the original algorithm is.

Comment: *"...you break the assumption..."*: the asker knows this, and they write *"If we find a shorter path to an already processed node, then we remove it from the list of processed nodes and add it to the heap"*. So they propose a solution to the problem you raise here. And there question is not whether they *can*, but whether the time complexity would remain the same.

Comment: @trincot "then why is it said that Dijkstra's algorithm does not work for negative weights?" a literal quote from the question here.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge that, but it is said in the context where the asker thinks they have found a modification of the algorithm that resolves the known issue. In the linked Q&A this modification isn't discussed. So the asker is actually saying: have those who said "it doesn't work" not looked at this modification?

Comment: @trincot fine let me edit the answer: the core problem of negative edge is never about what do I use to keep my stuff, heap, hash, etc etc. It's the fact you have to run through all edges multiple times. Regardless what you use if you don't do O(V*E) you can't solve it. So it's not a constant factor, and which is why after modifying literally how it works is no longer called the Dijkstra's algorithm, because that's not what the original algorithm is.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but *"you have to run through all edges multiple times"* is not an argument that they could not achieve the same time complexity. If you run 5 times through all edges, there is no change to the time complexity. *"if you don't do O(V\*E) you can't solve it"*: note that Dijkstra's algorithm does not have a worst case time complexity of O(V\*E).

Comment: @trincot Because to solve negative edge, it's no longer THE dijkstra algorithm, it's Bellman Ford or SPAF which has O(V*E) (worst case). You have to run through all the edges at worst case V-1 times to solve this problem, resulting O(V*E).

Comment: Right, that is more precise. The V-1 is important in that statement. "Multiple" does not cover it, as 5 is also "multiple".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple, intuition-level argument for why such an algorithm can never be equivalent to Djikstra:

Suppose in some huge graph, your target is one edge away from your origin, and that's the lightest-weight edge from your source. I claim it's an intrinsic property of Djikstra that the algorithm will not even **look** at the rest of the huge graph; it goes straight to the sink and returns immediately.

If negative edge weights are allowed, this is not safe; there could be some sequence of negative edges elsewhere in the graph which could result in a lower-weight total path, so the entire graph must be considered.

This case may seem contrived, but it speaks to the heart of Djikstra's algorithm - the growing set of nodes for which we know we have found the shortest path, which we expand as we consider additional nodes. If negative edge weights are allowed, this set cannot have any members - we can never know we've found the lowest-weight path until we've inspected every edge.