# What would happen if Dijkstra's algorithm is run on a directed graph with a negative weight cycle?

Tags: cycle, dijkstra

Let's say Dijkstra is run from a random vertex and it meets a negative-weight cycle on the path. We can loop around the cycle to make the cost as small as possible, but Dijkstra's invariant is not to "re-visit" the visited nodes, so I suppose there won't be an infinite loop and Dijkstra would terminate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that Dijkstra's algorithm wouldn't terminate, it's that Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work on graphs with negative weights at all. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6799344/57318) for an explanation of why.

Comment: but is there a way to detect a negative cycle in a graph using Dijkstra then?

Comment: @Mariska You shouldn't be running Dijkstra's on graphs that might have negative weights. So, no, there is not.